# Simulating nav menu borders with images instead of borders in CSS

Tags: css

What I'm after is a menu that looks something like this:

```
| one | two | three | four|
```

Using CSS and borders one can accomplish something similar to this by:

```
.myContainer > ul > li{
    border-right: 1px solid purple;
}

.myContainer > ul > li:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid purple;
}
```

I have been provided vertical images that the customer would like to use as the borders. Great. No biggie. Until I tried to implement it:

```
.nav-main > ul > li{           
    background: url('/Images/vertLine.png')no-repeat right top;
}

.nav-main > ul > li:first-child{           
    background: url('/Images/vertLine.png')no-repeat left top;
}
```

The output that this gives me is:

```
| one  two | three | four|
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this using images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutiple background images

```
.nav-main > ul > li{           
    background: url('/Images/vertLine.png')no-repeat right top;
}

.nav-main > ul > li:first-child{           
    background: 
      url('/Images/vertLine.png')no-repeat left top,
      url('/Images/vertLine.png')no-repeat right top;
}
```